# How can I add a simple effects or action to the image when click on it?

Tags: android, mobile-application

I'm using the **click on image** for starting another activity of my application, But I cant make sure I have clicked on it, So, how can I add simple effects or action on the image when I clicking on it.

Comment: Add a Toast.make(this,"onClicked",Toast.LONG);.show(); in your onClick listener.

Comment: This question is too broad - please edit your question with details on what specific effect you are trying to achieve and what have you attempted to date (along with what hasn't worked, and code).

Comment: you can add toast.. Or Add Ripple Effect While Clicking

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Toast.makeText(context,"Image clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

or alternatively you can use [log](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html). To use log:

```
Log.e("Image","clicked");
```

and see the logs in your Logcat of studio.